# Sending firebase push notificationto ios

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have tried to send Firebase push notifications to iOS and Android. But the following code is working with Android only not with iOS.

```
 try {
        const pushNotification = {
            token: deviceId,
            data: {
                title: title,
                body: body,
                notificationData: JSON.stringify(notificationData),
            },
            // Set Android priority to "high"
            android: {
                priority: "high",
            },
            // Add APNS (Apple) config
            apns: {
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        contentAvailable: true,
                    },
                },
                headers: {
                    //     "apns-push-type": "background",
                    "apns-priority": "5", // Must be `5` when `contentAvailable` is set to true.
                    //     "apns-topic": "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging", // bundle identifier
                },
            },
        };
        let notificationRes = await admin.messaging().send(pushNotification);

        // notification: {
        //         title: "Notification Title",
        //         body: "Notification Body",
        //     },
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.errorInfo);
        console.log(deviceId);
        if (
            error.errorInfo.code ===
            "messaging/registration-token-not-registered"
        ) {
            await employeeModel.updateMany(
                {
                    deviceId: deviceId,
                },
                {
                    $pull: { deviceId: deviceId },
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

IS there is any wrong with this code or i have to do something else for IOS